# Hibernate Mapping Error due to this exception. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am trying to fetch user details by id from 'User_Details' table.

But, It's giving the Exception, I know this is simple but I am trying this with HikariCP Connection pool.Need help to resolve.

I am having only 2 columns in that table:

1. ID
2. NAME

This is the Entity Mapping Pojo:

```
package com.example.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//Mapping Unique ID
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
private int id;
//User Name For Employee
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false )
private String name;
// getters and setters    
}
```

Mapping Exception :

```
   > org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: UserDetails is
   > not mapped at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

From the UserDetailsDaoImpl, I am trying to fetch the details.

```
package com.example.repository;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.example.model.UserDetails;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public UserDetails getUser(int id){
    UserDetails userDetails = null;
    Session s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query q = s.createQuery("From UserDetails Where id =:id ").setParameter("id", id);
    List<UserDetails> u = q.list();
    if(!u.isEmpty()){
        userDetails = u.get(0);
    }
    return userDetails!= null? userDetails : null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: seems like you have not add the entity in hibernate xml

Comment: `UserDetails is not mapped` which means You are trying to use the entity which doesn't have any mapping. you may need to share your code where you are trying to perform DB query. Also, try to use class name instead of table name in query

Comment: can you please share your hibernate-cfg.xml file.

Comment: It's really great if you provide the configuration class also. By the way, I suppose maybe configuration issue. please look in this example https://o7planning.org/en/11665/spring-boot-hibernate-and-spring-transaction-tutorial

Comment: @Killer why did you remove the stack trace? I keep asking for stack traces as they are kind of valueable. I'm wired on how that edit could be approved.

Comment: @Selaron : There is nothing much on that trace, I only kept what is useful. That first  line say it all about the problem.